# Destroying passport user session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I have a react front and node/express/passport backend. Currently I have an end point that returns req.user object to me.

```
router.route('/userauth') 
 .get(authHelpers.getAuthUser)
```

---

I have a logout endpoint that looks like this

```
router.route('/logout')
.get(function (req, res){
 delete req.session;
 req.session.destroy(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
 });
})
```

---

When I logout I hit the endpoint and I redirect to homepage the problem is when my homepage loads it hits the first end point for (req.user) if there is no req.user it request you authentic if not it shows content.

Right now it still show a req.user. my logout endpoint doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

you are deleting the session object before you are using the built in destroy method.

```
router.route('/logout')
.get(function (req, res){
  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
})
```

see this for reference:

https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiondestroycallback